# Change chart property with onClick event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to change data vizualization with an `onClick` event. But since property is defined when chart is called I can´t get the property to update. I'm using a button from exporting menu, so I don´t think using a jQuery method to update would work.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```js
          customButton: {
            text: "Update",
            onclick: function() {
              if (!isStackingPercentage) {
                handlePercentageClick()
                //redraw chart?
              }
              else if (isStackingPercentage) {
                handleStackingClick()
                //redraw chart?
              }
            }
          }
```

The property is defined this way

```js
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: isStackingPercentage ? "percent" : "stacking",
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/e612gsuh/40/) is a working example

Comment: I've found this example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/chart-update/, but I don't think I have acces to `chart.update` inside `onClick()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access chart reference through `this` in `onclick` function and use `update` method:

```
  exporting: {
    buttons: {
      customButton: {
        text: "Update",
        onclick: function() {
          if (!isStackingPercentage) {
            handlePercentageClick();
            this.update({
              plotOptions: {
                column: {
                  stacking: 'percent'
                }
              }
            });
          } else if (isStackingPercentage) {
            handleStackingClick();
            this.update({
              plotOptions: {
                column: {
                  stacking: 'normal'
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rb584w70/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update